# chrome.tabs.executeScript - How to inject code with keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

How can I trigger enter event with chrome.tabs.executeScript

My code below doesn't work :(

**script.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"jquery.js"}, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: `
            var word = "bla bla";
            var enter = $.Event("keydown", {
                keyCode: 13
            });

            $("#chatbox").val(${word}).trigger(enter);
        `
    });
});
```